# bitronix- Unable to locate current JTA transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, bitronix

Hi I have a Java web application using spring and hibernate.

I have a model class called **Role**. For all model classes there is common **GenericDao.java**

```
public interface GenericDao<T>{
    public void insert(T transientInstance);      
    public T findById(Class<?> clazz, Serializable id); 
}
```

**GenericHibernateDao.java**

```
@Repository
public class GenericHibernateDao<T extends Serializable>
implements GenericDao<T>{

    @Resource
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void insert(T transientInstance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
    }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T findById(Class<?> clazz, Serializable id) {
        return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
        }
}
```

**RoleService.java**

```
public interface RoleService {
    public void insert(Role role);
    public Role findById(Integer id);
}
```

And has its implementation **RoleServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<Role> roleDao;

    @Override
    public void insert(Role role) {
        roleDao.insert(role);
    }

    @Override
    public Role findById(Integer id) {
        return roleDao.findById(Role.class, id);
    }
}
```

I have a controller which calls this **findbyid** methid and passing a value - **RegisterController.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserRegisterController {

    @Autowired
    public RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void registerUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        Role role=new Role();
        role=roleService.findById(1);
        System.out.println("Saved");
    }
}
```

Finally my spring **applicationContext.xml** is

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource"
        init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="className"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" />
        <property name="uniqueName" value="ocr/DocumentDatabase" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="automaticEnlistingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="true" />
        <property name="useTmJoin" value="true" />
        <property name="shareTransactionConnections" value="true" />
        <property name="driverProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
                <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
                <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="bitronixTransactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager"
        class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig, dataSource"
        destroy-method="shutdown" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="bitronixTransactionManager" />
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="bitronixTransactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I run this application in **tomcat**. It gives the following error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myappdemo] in context with path [/myappdemo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:980)
    at com.myapp.myappdemo.dao.hibernate.GenericHibernateDao.findById(GenericHibernateDao.java:46)
    at com.myapp.myappdemo.dao.hibernate.GenericHibernateDao.findById(GenericHibernateDao.java:15)
    at com.myapp.myappdemo.service.impl.RoleServiceImpl.findById(RoleServiceImpl.java:38)
    at com.myapp.myappdemo.web.UserRegisterController.registerUser(UserRegisterController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

It happens when I call the `roleService.findById(1);`

Why its happening? And how can I resolve?

I am using spring 3.2.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.2.0.Final, btm 2.1.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sessionFactory is configured to use JtaTransactionManager. When you do that, hibernate is smart enough to look into current transactionnal resources to find the session.

Your spring configuration allows you to use annotations to do transaction demarcation.

Your transaction manager seems correctly configured.

So, everything looks fine. The only missing part are the transactional annotations !

Just add `@Transactional` in your service layer:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Role findById(Integer id) {
    return roleDao.findById(Role.class, id);
}
```

(you can also put this annotation on the service class)

Comment: In the service class I put. That time I am getting `transaction timedout exception`

Comment: So it seems that `Unable to locate current JTA transaction` is fixed. Please accept the answer and ask another question about transaction timed out (if you didn't solve it yet). Don't forget to post your spring config (like on this post + btmConfig bean) and the stacktrace.